# Wix - Error when building setup package - ERROR CNDL0200 (unhandled extension element)

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

Hello I'm having trouble building this WiX installation package... I'm using the Wix utilExtensions and added it to the references of the installation project. Upon building the package i get the following error;

[image]

Provided XML code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Fragment>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <!--Creates the Roaming folder required for local document    saving-->
      <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="ROAMINGFOLDER" Name="App">
          <Component Id="ROAMINGFOLDER" Guid="*">
            <RemoveFolder Id="ROAMINGFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKMU"
                           Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Roaming"
                           Type="string"
                           Value="App Roaming Folder" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="My App">

          <Component Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Guid="*">
            <RemoveFolder  Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
                       On="both"  />
            <util:RemoveFolderEx Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKMU"
                           Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"
                           Type="string"
                           Value="My App" />
          </Component>
...
```

Any idea's on solving this particular issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you haven't actually provided  WixUtilExtension dll to the build. It depends on how you're building, but in Visual Studio you'd add the Dll to the References node, otherwise on the command line you'd use -ext  WixUtilExtension on the candle command line, and have the Dll available in the build location.

Comment: Thanks, but i already added the dll to the installer references, that's what is weird about this issue. But i can try that second part. Thanks